# Select Sheet chosen via ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select cells of an Excel Sheet like

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
```

But instead of the hardcoded Sheetname `"Sheet1"` I would like to select the one that is selected in the `ComboBox1`.
Its items are provided by

```
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
'       Skip empty sheets and hidden sheets
        If Application.CountA(currentsheet.Cells) <> 0 And _
            currentsheet.Visible Then
            MsgBox currentsheet.Name
            ComboBox1.AddItem (currentsheet.Name)
        End If
Next i
```

Comment: Like: `With Sheets(ComboBox1.Value)`?

Comment: I was trying this but got the error "types incompatible", but there was something wrong... now its working :D

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you populate the ComboBox1 only with values of worksheet names that exist, but maybe not.  It's likely causing an error if a ComboBox1.value is an integer or an empty string.  You should try:

```
sheet_name = CStr(ComboBox1.Value)
If Len(sheet_name) > 0 Then
With Sheets(sheet_name)
```